# How do you mix JS and Ruby code in a view for later JS usage?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am using a jquery UI DatePicker widget to show a calendar. Each day in the calendar is represented by a collection of Result object, which belong to an Objective model.
If all the results for a day are succesful, I'm setting a class on the calendar cell, to make it green. If at least one of them failed, I'm making it red. If no results exists, I'm making it grey. Right now , I do something like this:

```
<%= start_day .. end_day do |day| %>
   <div class="hidethis" id="<%= [day.year,day.month,day.year].join(",") %>" value="<%= objective.result_status_for_day(day)%>"/>
<% end %>
```

I am storing data in hidden divs, and later, when I'm initializing the calendar, in the beforeShowDay I'm going through the div ids to find the one relevant to me, and I set the class responsible for colouring the cell. Is there another way of doing this, or is this something which other people use in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using HTML for data storage seems a bit round-about. Why not store your data as JavaScript data? Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.app = window.app || { };
    window.app.objective_data = <%= @raw_objective_data.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

Then set up your raw data in Ruby, leave it in `@raw_objective_data`, and then load it into your client-side models during your initialization pass. Or you could load the data straight into your (Java|Coffee)Script through a simple AJAX call.

You'll also want to avoid `'</script>'` and similar things in `@raw_objective_data.to_json`, you can learn about that [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249932/479863).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the id and value attributes. I don't think the div tag even supports the value attribute. Instead I'd use data attributes, which allow you to write valid HTML markup while simultaneously embedding data within your page.

```
<%= start_day .. end_day do |day| %>
   <div class="hidethis" data-date="<%= [day.year,day.month,day.year].join(",") %>" data-value="<%= objective.result_status_for_day(day)%>"></div>
<% end %>

var value = $('div').attr('data-value');
```