# Escaping </script> tag inside javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, haml

I'm using backbone, and the general way for passing the collections when the page load is

```
window.router = new Routers.ManageRouter({store: #{@store.to_json});
```

which is fine and works well, until someone decides to add the text "`<script>alert("owned")</script>`" to one of the store fields. the last `</script>` obviously closes the javascript. How can this be circumvented?

```
  :javascript
    $(function() {
      window.router = new Dotz.Routers.ManageRouter({store: #{@store.to_json}});
      Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

**The above outputs:**

```
<script>
    //<![CDATA[
      $(function() {
        window.router = new Dotz.Routers.ManageRouter({store: '{"_id":"4f3300e19c2ee41d9a00001c", "points_text":"<script>alert(\"hey\");</script>"'});
        Backbone.history.start();
      });
    //]]>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside a `<script>` block it is [syntactically illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32-19970114#script) to have any `</` followed by a name—not just `</script>`—so you need to escape that anywhere it may appear. For example:

```
:javascript
   var foo = { store: #{@store.to_json.gsub('</','<\/')} };
```

This will create the sequence `<\/` inside your JS strings, which is interpreted to be the  same as `</`. Ensure that you use single quotes in your gsub replacement string, or else use `gsub( "</", "<\\/" )` due to the difference between single and double quotes in Ruby.

Shown in action:

```
irb:02.0> s = "<b>foo</b>" # Here's a dangerous string
#=> "<b>foo</b>"

irb:03.0> a = [s]          # Wrapped in an array, for fun.
#=> ["<b>foo</b>"]

irb:04.0> json = a.to_json.gsub( '</', '<\/' )  # Sanitized
irb:05.0> puts json        # This is what would come out in your HTML; safe!
#=> ["<b>foo<\/b>"]

irb:06.0> puts JSON.parse(json).first  # Same as the original? Yes! Yay!
#=> <b>foo</b>
```

If you are using Rails (or ActiveSupport) you can enable [JSON escaping](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/JSON/Encoding/escape_html_entities_in_json%3D/class):

```
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
```

Seen in action:

```
irb:02.0> a = ["<b>foo</b>"]
irb:03.0> puts a.to_json # Without the magic
#=> ["<b>foo</b>"]

irb:04.0> require 'active_support'
irb:05.0> ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
irb:06.0> puts a.to_json # With the magic
#=> ["\u003Cb\u003Efoo\u003C/b\u003E"]
```

It produces JSON that is more verbose than you need to solve this particular problem, but it is effective.

Answer (score 4):

The magic word is:

```
ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
```

Although marked as deprecated, this still works in current rails versions (see my `rails c`):

```
ruby-1.9.3-head :001 > ::Rails.version
 => "3.2.1" 
ruby-1.9.3-head :002 > ["<>"].to_json
 => "[\"<>\"]" 
ruby-1.9.3-head :003 > ActiveSupport.escape_html_entities_in_json = true
 => true 
ruby-1.9.3-head :004 > ["<>"].to_json
 => "[\"\\u003C\\u003E\"]"
```

Comment: This form was [discontinued in Rails v2.3.3+](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/escape_html_entities_in_json%3D/class)

Comment: Odd; perhaps they or you have a backwards compatibility shim. It does not work in raw ActiveSupport v3.0.7; nonetheless I'll remove my downvote on your word that it works.

Comment: This works great in my Rails 3.2.13 application.  I wonder why the ActiveSupport team would deprecate such a useful, security-related feature.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the ''

```
:javascript
    $(function() {
      window.router = new Dotz.Routers.ManageRouter({store: '#{@store.to_json}'});
      Backbone.history.start();
    });
```

Comment: nope. it will still render something like `{id: '324234', text: '</script>'...` while will close the script

Comment: can you post the HTML of the rendered page please ?