# Prevent JS from parsing string

Tags: javascript

Was playing around with some code and just realized you can't write a script tag in a string without the browser trying to display:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    var code = "<script></script>";
  </script>
</head>
```

This prints to the screen. Weird - why this behavior?

Comment: whats your concrete problem?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3509818/218196, or many of these http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%3C%2Fscript%3E%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JavaScript "string parsing". Rather it's about *HTML* parsing.

It is simply *not valid* for HTML for a `<script>` element to contain the sequence `</script>` (actually, any `</` although browsers are lenient on that) in it's content - any such sequence will *always* be treated as the closing tag.

See [Escaping </script> tag inside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9246382/2864740) for lots of the details.

---

A common solution is thus to separate the sequence using string concatenation

```
var code = "<script><"+"/script>";
```

Although it is also valid to use an escape (`"<script><\/script>"`) or an escape sequence (`"<script><\x2fscript>"`).

The `CDATA` approach should [*not* be used with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092256/2864740), as it's only for XML.

Comment: Ah of course - I was not thinking this through!

Comment: I expect the `"<\/"` version is better, as the script parser may turn `'<' + '/'` into `'</'` and see a closing tag.

Comment: @RobG No JavaScript parsing occurs before HTML script element is parsed - then the entire content is turned over to JS only *after* the HTML parser reads through the end of the element. I'm not sure why, and I can't argue why it'd be "better", but the string concatenation version seems to be the most prevalent in my experience.